# Is it possible that $1\otimes 1 = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.

Let $A,B$ be $R$-algebras and consider their product $A\otimes_R B$.

Is it possible that $1\otimes 1=0$? What is an example?

If $R$ is a field, $1\otimes 1$ is never a zero, but I'm not sure whether it true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb Z$, $A=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $B=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.
Then $1\otimes 1 = 3(1\otimes 1)-2(1\otimes 1)=1\otimes 3-2\otimes 1=0$ (and in effect $A\otimes B=0$).

Comment: Is there a criterion to check whether $a\otimes b$ is zero when $a,b$ are nonzero? Say $A,B$ are torsion-free, then is $a\otimes b$ nonzero?